# Расширение для браузера

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Вообщем решил сделать расширение для опера типа instant view у телеграм, только для фейсбук. Чтобы ссылки на статьи в записях можно было открывать внутри самого фейсбук. Первый вопрос. Законно ли это. Слышал фейсбук запрещает парсить свой сайт и, как через js найти посты с ссылками, что бы вставить свою кнопку(в исходном коде фб немойми что).
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, лицензия от фейсбука запрещает использовать контент (кроме вашего собственного) иначе, чем через свой API. Не знаю, какая реакция может  последовать (не юрист), но, как минимум, стоит перечитать всю юр. информацию.